# can Nginx randomly stop working by certain requests?

Tags: linux, nginx, .net-core

I'm currently having issues with my website. Sometimes, after a fresh restart of nginx service the url of my website works just fine in the browser, It redirects successfully to the .NET Core webapp running on Kestrel.If I type the IP of my vps it also works just fine. But suddenly and randomly nginx stops serving the website and the browser just shows *err_connection_closed*.

Some technical information:
Kestrel is running on localhost:5000, Nginx TCP ports are managed by ufw and opened for: 80 and 443.

I'm using: Ubuntu 16.04, nginx and a .NET Core 3.1 web app. Steps were followed as next url [Host and Deploy using Linux and Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Something that I have noticed in syslog file is that some IPs are blocked by ufw, but I'm not sure why they are coming from China, Mongolia or even Poland, as the initial marketing campaign is currently located for Mexico.

Other log file that I searched in was /var/log/nginx/access.log Here, some IPs try to request random urls in my website like GET /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" or even like "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" which is absolutely not me because I'm using PostgreSQL. Although, I have to say that I've seen that after this requests are randomly made, the nginx stops working but I'm not 100% sure if this is accurate, as seen in the title, this is very random.

Some config files for nginx:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   keecheeapp.com *.keecheeapp.com;
    location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/proxy_conf**

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
#other directives

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include        /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
    server_tokens  off;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout   29; # Adjust to the lowest possible value that makes sense for your use case.
    client_body_timeout 10; client_header_timeout 10; send_timeout 10;

    upstream keecheeapp{
        server localhost:5000;
    }

    server {
    listen     *:80;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        return     301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen                    *:443 ssl;
        server_name               keecheeapp.com;
        ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/keecheeapp.com-concat-certs.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/certs/private_new.key;
        ssl_protocols             TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers               "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve            secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets       off;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        #Redirects all traffic
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://www.keecheeapp.com;
            limit_req  zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your Nginx configuration:

- In the file **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

  - The combination of `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;` and `limit_req  zone=one burst=10 nodelay;` will limit the request processing rate per client to 5 requests/second. If you send too many requests per second then you will get error messages from Nginx. So if you want to keep the limit feature, try to increase the existing value to, for example, `rate=50r/s` and `burst=100`. If you want to disable this feature, delete or comment out those lines. You can learn more about this feature [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).
  - The value `http://www.keecheeapp.com` for the `proxy_pass` directive is wrong . The correct value is `keecheeapp` as defined by the `upstream keecheeapp {...}` block. So change `proxy_pass http://www.keecheeapp.com;` to `proxy_pass http://keecheeapp;`
- The server block in the file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** instructs Nginx to serve your website using HTTP.

  The following server block in the file **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** instructs Nginx to serve your website using HTTPS.

  ```
  server {
      listen                    *:443 ssl;
      server_name               keecheeapp.com;
      ...
  }
  ```

  So your website is accessible over both HTTP and HTTPS. It's not a good idea. You should redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS as follows:

  - Delete or comment out the server block in in the file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**
  - Modify the following server block in the file **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

    ```
    server {
    listen     *:80;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        return     301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    ```

    To:

    ```
    server {
        listen     *:80;
        server_name   keecheeapp.com *.keecheeapp.com;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        return     301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    ```
- With your given configuration, Nginx is passing all requests to Kestrel, including static file requests (image, JS, CSS, etc.). This is unrealistic. Let Nginx handle static files, and Kestrel handles dynamic requests. Please change the following configuration block:

  ```
        #Redirects all traffic
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://www.keecheeapp.com;
            limit_req  zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        }
  ```

  To:

  ```
        root /path/to/your/static/folder;

        # Serve static file requests
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @kestrel;
        }

        # Pass dynamic requests to Kestrel
        location @kestrel {
            proxy_pass http://keecheeapp;
            limit_req  zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        }
  ```

  Change `/path/to/your/static/folder` to the actual folder on your server.

After editing, don't forget to test Nginx configuration with `sudo nginx -t`, then reload it with `sudo systemctl reload nginx.service`.

Comment: I followed your instructions Tom and thanks for your suggestions. But certainly the problem is still happening. I mean, it worked just fine for around 10 minutes, in the syslog file there's not a single error arised. 

And I didn' do anything else, I did not even manually restarted nginx but all of a sudden it is working again. When running systemctl status nginx it always says active(running) and no error message is found in the logs.

But it feels like the request from https://www.keecheeapp.com does not even reach the server as no message is found in syslog when trying to open the site.

Comment: Perhaps this could be a problem with the DNS records? Although I have the required ones such as: Type: A host: @ and Value: my ip address and another one Type: CNAME host: www and value: @. So I'm not really sure what is going on. 

Comment: Your DNS settings are correct. To temporarily bypass the DNS problem, you can set your IP directly with your hosts file. If you don't know how to do it, use a search engine to search for something like "how to edit hosts file". After editing, your computer will no longer perform DNS queries for your domains. It will use whatever IP you put in your hosts file. You have to add the following two lines in the hosts file:   
`11.22.33.44 keecheeapp.com` and `11.22.33.44 www.keecheeapp.com`. Please replace `11.22.33.44` with your server IP.

Comment: To bypass problems caused by the browser's cache, clear the cache, then reopen your browser before testing. Again, ensure that there is no `proxy_pass http://www.keecheeapp.com;` in your Nginx configuration. I did a mistake due to copy/paste in my answer. So the location block `location @kestrel {...} ` did contain `proxy_pass http://www.keecheeapp.com;`. I edited my answer to change it to `proxy_pass http://keecheeapp;`.

Comment: A common tip: If you get an error, immediately open your terminal and ping your domain to see if the error is caused by DNS.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Certainly after having a look, I'm still not sure now why the err_connection_closed error happens when trying to access to www.keecheeapp.com but with keecheeapp.com IP resolves just fine. Perhaps some other configuration is needed. I accepted the answer because it certainly helped me a lot.

Comment: It looks like it was a problem with the DNS. It was resolving to two different IPs, that's why sometimes it showed my website and sometimes not. Also, I noticed that I had an A record pointing to / which I'm not sure why it was there so I removed it from the DNS records, and now the DNS correctly resolves to only one IP by checking on an online DNS Propagation Tool. It seems working smoothly so far.